QGIS enmap-box plugin
I want to use the plugin enMAP-box3. Currently I use QGIS 3.34-6 on my Macbook. The following error keeps occurring when installing the plugin:
Couldn't load plugin 'enmapboxplugin' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
ImportError: cannot import name 'DMD_CREATIONFIELDDATASUBTYPES' from 'osgeo.gdalconst' (/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/GDAL-3.3.2-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/gdalconst.py)
How can I solve it?

The GDAL version (3.3.2) is too old (see https://github.com/EnMAP-Box/enmap-box/issues/843).
You need to install QGIS with a more recent GDAL (e.g. 3.9.), e.g. using QGIS apps provided by OpenGIS or a conda environment
See:
https://github.com/opengisch/qgis-conda-builder/releases)
https://enmap-box.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usr_section/usr_installation.html#qgis-installation-on-macos for
